# Open file in Android O not working, however successfull on api 25

Tags: android, android-intent, android-package-managers

I am experiencing some trouble with opening files on Android O (api 26).

In Android O when I tab the notification **after successfull download**, nothing happens (notification just gets deleted), however when I do the same in in api 25 the file opens as it should be and it works.

Debugging points out the the method **canOpenFile always returns false** on api 26.

Did I overlook something?
Any help is appreciated, many thx.

Notification code:

```
public void finishedNotification(int id, String appName, String urlPath, boolean success) {
        initSoundChannels(this);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "default");

        notification.setContentTitle(appName)
                .setContentText(success ? "Successfully downloaded" : "Download failed - file deleted")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_noti)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setColor(mApplication_.getInstance().getResources().getColor(R.color.apps_color))
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mApplication_.getInstance().getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setOngoing(false)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        if (success) {
            if (canOpenFile(urlPath)) { // ALWAYS false on API26??
                PendingIntent openFile = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                        ACTION_OPEN_FILE.hashCode() + id,
                        openFile(urlPath),
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                notification.setContentIntent(openFile);
            } else { // being executed on api 26
                PendingIntent openDownloads = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
                        ACTION_OPEN_DOWNLOADS.hashCode() + id,
                        new Intent(ACTION_OPEN_FILE),
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                notification.setContentIntent(openDownloads);
            }
        } else {
            Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(ACTION_FILE_CANCEL);
            cancelIntent.putExtra("id", id);
            PendingIntent cancel = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mApplication_.getInstance(),
                    ACTION_FILE_CANCEL.hashCode() + id,
                    cancelIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            notification.setContentIntent(cancel);
        }

        Notification builtNotification = notification.build();
        getNotificationManager().notify(id, builtNotification);
    }
```

Openfile Intent:

```
private Intent openFile(String urlPath) {
        File file = new File(urlPath);

        Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        String ext = file.getName().substring(file.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
            target.setDataAndType(uri, type);
            target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            target.setDataAndType(uri, type);
            target.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        }
        return target;
    }
```

CanOpenfile:

```
private boolean canOpenFile(String urlPath) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        File file = new File(urlPath);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
        ResolveInfo info = pm.resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        return info != null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues that may be contributing to your problems.

First, you are using implicit broadcasts (action strings instead of component names), to what would appear to be your own app. That was never a particularly good idea from a security standpoint, and on Android 8.0+, implicit broadcasts are banned in general. So, replace `new Intent(ACTION_OPEN_FILE)` with `new Intent(this, WhateverTheReceiverClassIs.class).setAction(ACTION_OPEN_FILE)`, where `WhateverTheReceiverClassIs` is whatever your `BroadcastReceiver` class is.

Second, `canOpenFile()` is using `Uri.fromFile()`, giving you a `file` scheme on the `Uri`. Since the `file` scheme was banned in general on Android 7.0, it is entirely possible that there is no app that offers an `<intent-filter>` for it on your Android 8.0 test environment. Moreover, that code does not match `openFile()`. Generate the `Uri` once and use it for both scenarios.